# Coproduct in the category of compact abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, abelian-groups, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

Denote by **Ab** the category of abelian groups and group homomorphisms and by **CAb** the category of compact Hausdorff abelian groups and continuous group homomorphisms. It follows from Pontryagin duality that **CAb** is equivalent to **Ab**$^{op}$, where  $^{op}$ denotes the opposite category. This is a consequence of the fact that a locally compact group is compact if and only if its dual is discrete and viceversa.

Now, **Ab** has both products and coproducts, so the same is true for **Ab**$^{op}$ and therefore also for **CAb**. Products in **CAb** are just the usual direct products endowed with the product topology. On the other hand, I find it much harder to understand coproducts in this category. Given a family $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ of compact abelian groups, one way to describe their coproduct is the following:
$$\coprod_{i\in I}G_i=\widehat{\prod_{i\in I}\widehat G_i}$$ where the hat denotes the Pontryagin dual and the product is endowed with the discrete topology.

Is there a "more concrete" way to describe the coproduct in **CAb**, that does not make use of duals?

Comment: I doubt there is any particularly nice description.  It is perhaps instructive to consider the case where $G_i$ is cyclic of order $p$ for all $i$ for some prime $p$.  Then the coproduct is the double dual of the direct sum as $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector spaces.  Up to isomorphism, this is just some huge product of copies of $\mathbb{F}_p$, but there isn't any canonical way to express it as such a product if the index set is infinite.